# How to reduce time take to retrieve objects from s3 bucket?

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I am handling objects which was stored in s3 bucket ( aws ) using php. It take more than 50seconds to retrieve objects from s3 bucket. So can anyone help me to retrieve objects effectively or please suggest any best logic to reduce time taken to download objects. Thanks in advance

Comment: It's difficult to suggest a solution, because what you are seeing is a problem that should not be happening... unless I have misunderstood your question.  Do you mean it takes 50 seconds to retrieve **a single object** or do you mean it takes more than 50 seconds to retrieve **a list of all objects**?

Comment: Please provide more information so that we can assist you. For example, how are you retrieving the object from S3 (SDK, CLI, Console)? What is the size of the object? Does it take 50 seconds to *start* the download, or to complete it? Also, in case latency is an issue, in which region is the S3 bucket and in which country are you located?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein It take 50 secs to retrieve list of all objects. I think the objects size may be in  KB only and it is in us-east-1 region.

Comment: From where are you running the "list all objects" command -- on an EC2 instance, or from your own computer? How many objects are in the bucket? What command are you using to obtain the listing? Please provide more information so that we can assist you.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein am accessing it from india. I think it may contain 1.2 million objects but i need to implement pagination on the page to display objects 10 by 10 for every next click

Comment: @JohnRotenstein am using get_object_list() method, but i have tried such similar methods to get objects. But i am failed.

Comment: Ah! So is your code retrieving that entire list of 1.2 million objects? Or is it only returning the first 1000? Which programming language are you using? Can you provide a snippet of your code in the Question? Also, if your question is related to "listing objects", then please update the Question since it currently says "retrieving objects", which implies downloading them.

Comment: am getting first 1000 objects only for a request, but i thought's to simply the retrieve by getting objects 10 by 10 using pagination, is it possible. I am using codeigniter framework of php.